# multiple websites on nginx & sites-available

Tags: linux, nginx, webserver

With the base install of nginx, your `sites-available` folder has just one file: `default`

how does the `sites-available` folder work and how would I use it to host multiple (separate) websites?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Just to add another approach, you can use a separate file for each virtual domain or site you're hosting.
You can use a copy of default as a starting point for each one and customize for each site.
Then create symlinks in sites-enabled.  In this way you can take sites up and down just by adding or removing a symlink and issuing a service nginx reload.

You can get creative and use this method to redirect sites to a maintenance mode page while you are doing site maintenance.

So the structure looks like this:

```
/sites-available/ (you can use obvious file names like this)
| 
|-> a.mysite.com
|-> b.mysite.com
|-> someOtherSite.com

/sites-enabled/ (these are just symlinks to the real files in /sites-available)
| 
|-> a.mysite.com
|-> b.mysite.com
```

Notice that since there are only the first two entries are the only symlinked items in `sites-enabled`, the third entry, `someOtherSite.com` is therefore offline.

Answer (score 32):

If you look at `nginx.conf`, you will find [`include`](http://nginx.org/r/include) directive that includes all files from the `sites-enabled` directory. This directory stores symlinks to config files from `sites-available` in order to be convenient to switch on and off parts of your configuration.

As you can see, there's no magic with these directories.

If you want to host multiple websites you should use multiple [`server`](http://nginx.org/r/server) blocks and/or [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/r/server_name) directive. Official tutorials are here: [Server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) and [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

Answer (score 21):

You symlink the default file from sites available to sites enabled.  Then you modify the available site to include two server blocks each with a different server_name.  see the following.  This assumes you have to domains called example.com and example2.com.  You would also have pointed your @records to the ip address of the server where you've installed nginx.

symlink the available site to an enabled site

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

edit the file using your editor of choice (vim for me)

```
sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Here's contents of working nginx conf, assuming you are running web apps on the port 4567 and 4568.

```
server {

    server_name www.example.com

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4567/;
    }

}


server {

    server_name www.example2.com

    location {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4568/;
    }

}
```