# Wordpress on Ubuntu w/ Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

I used this [tutorial from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-single-and-multiple-wordpress-site-settings-with-nginx)
I am not able to get my vps to work with just one wordpress site with nginx.
Eventually I want to have 2 Wordpress sites on 2 different directories on the same server.

I included all 3 `.conf` files `wordress.conf`, `common.conf` & `multisite.conf` just like it says in the tutorial.

`nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss textjavascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example` that is symlinked from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example`

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
server {
  server_name www.example.com;  
  root /var/www/example;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.error.log;
  include global/common.conf;
  include global/wordpress.conf;
}
```

`wordpress.conf`

```
# WORDPRESS : Rewrite rules, sends everything through index.php and keeps the appended query string intact
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

# SECURITY : Deny all attempts to access PHP Files in the uploads directory
location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}
# REQUIREMENTS : Enable PHP Support
location ~ \.php$ {
    # SECURITY : Zero day Exploit Protection
    try_files $uri =404;
    # ENABLE : Enable PHP, listen fpm sock
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
# PLUGINS : Enable Rewrite Rules for Yoast SEO SiteMap
rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;

#Yeah! you did it.
```

`common.conf`

```
# Global configuration file.
# ESSENTIAL : Configure Nginx Listening Port
listen 80;
# ESSENTIAL : Default file to serve. If the first file isn't found, 
index index.php index.html index.htm;
# ESSENTIAL : no favicon logs
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
# ESSENTIAL : robots.txt
location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
# ESSENTIAL : Configure 404 Pages
error_page 404 /404.html;
# ESSENTIAL : Configure 50x Pages
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }
# SECURITY : Deny all attempts to access hidden files .abcde
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}
# PERFORMANCE : Set expires headers for static files and turn off logging.
location ~* ^.+\.(js|css|swf|xml|txt|ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    access_log off; log_not_found off; expires 30d;
}
```

`multisite.conf`

```
# Rewrite rules for WordPress Multi-site.
if (!-e $request_filename) {
  rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
  rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
  rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
}
```

I configured the `wp-config.php` file as well. 
Created my MySQL user and made sure the user has access to the database.
Also changed the permissions of `/var/www/example` with `chmod -R 755 .`

And I have nothing on my logs:
`/var/log/nginx/www.example.com.access.log` nor `/var/log/nginx/www.example.com.error.log` files have been created.

When I `curl` or `telnet` I get a `connection refused`
`telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xx` or `telnet example.com`

```
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xx...
telnet: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xx: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

`curl xxx.xxx.xxx.xx` or `curl example.com`

```
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx port 80: Connection refused`
```

Comment: what happens when you launch nginx ? does it say it started ?

Comment: Go with this.. it will help you a lot

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693135/multiple-websites-on-nginx-sites-available

Comment: nginx starts without a problem. `[OK]`

Comment: try my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57018937/848677