# NGINX Multiple Site Setup

Tags: nginx

Basically, my NGINX setup is working fine for 2 of my sites but adding a third redirects to the second one.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html/link.com/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.link.com link.com;

    location / {

        # URLs to attempt, including pretty ones.
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}



user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My other 3 sites have the same config but editted accordingly. I also have a default section.

All 4 sites have a symbolic link in sites-enabled. I also havent editted the nginx.conf I dont think.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Did you add a third 'site' or 'location' ? Check your upstream configuration in nginx.conf. Ok from the description guess its a site. My best guess is a config problem in nginx.conf

Comment: I've included the nginx config. Uneditted from how it was (I think)

Comment: Sorry. [Upstream](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) is only used for defining server groups. Here are few links - [full-config](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/), [server-block](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/), [one-more-example](https://nginx.org/en/docs/example.html). Check if you have unique domains in each of the cases where server-blocks are defined - including default. Ensure the log-paths for each of the server blocks are unique and re-validate that they are handing requests as expected

Comment: @RavindraHV I have my server blocks in their own files in sites-available eg for site1.com the server block will be in site1.com in sites-available and site2.com will have a similar file in site2.com is this not right?

Comment: That sounds right but then you shouldn't be having any problems in that case. Which is why the best way to troubleshoot is to first ensure that the requests for each site is indeed being processed by the server section intended for it - have unique access log file locations and verify that in the 2-site configuration the requests are indeed hitting the server-blocks that you think they should be. That's about all I can say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just consolidating the links in the comments above and adding a few more for reference :

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/

https://nginx.org/en/docs/example.html

+

[multiple websites on nginx & sites-available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693135/multiple-websites-on-nginx-sites-available)

Below two are in turn referenced in one of the answers in the above SO post :

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

+

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

While its not quite the standard SO answer, until someone else with better understanding comes along, you can refer these.