# Install GitLab on box with existing Git server

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm currently in the process of seeking a GUI to add to our existing Git setup, we've looked at a few options but GitLab seems to be at the top of the list due to the documentation and community backing. One of the things holding us back from moving forward with the integration is the feasibility of seamlessly adding it to our stack without interruption or data loss.

After searching through their forums, and more generalized development forums (such as this one) I have yet to come across someone outlining exactly how this process is handled with GitLab. Is there a way to integrate an existing Git setup directly into GitLab during the install, or does each repository have to be migrated manually after GitLab is installed?

I'm aware of the Rake task documented here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/import.md which allows repositories to be imported, but I'm not 100% that it's the solution here.

Is it possible to install GitLab on a server which has a standard git server running without disruption of service, manually updating the refs for each repository as time goes on, or does GitLab ship with its own Git instance that will break the current one?

Any insight into this process, or tips on how to achieve a smooth transition into better version control is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to install GitLab on a server which has a standard git server running without disruption of service

Yes: a "Git server" is just a collection of bare repos accessed through a listener (Apache or NGinX)

GitLab can use its own listener, installed separately, or declared [as a new "`site_available`" in an existing NGiNX instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11701994/6309): as long as it uses a different port and path URL, your existing repos are safe.

Then, once GitLab is up and running (with no repos), you can start importing them and communicate the new remote URL to use.

Comment: He is asking to reuse the existing git repository without migrating it

Comment: @ftrujillo That is possible indeed: I would have like a feedback, but the OP has not been seen here since 2018.